# Setting a setState to another state value in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state

I have a React exercise about using states in class components. My solution works well when I code as below:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { lat: null, errorMessage: "" };

    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude }),
      (err) => this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message })
    );
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.lat && !this.state.errorMessage) {
      return <div>Latitude: {this.state.lat}</div>;
    } else if (!this.state.lat && this.state.errorMessage) {
      return <div>Erroe: {this.state.errorMessage}</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Latitude: Loading...</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But when I write it in another way, I get no error but no output

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { lat: null, errorMessage: "", message: "" };

    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude }),
      (err) => this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message })
    );
    if (this.state.lat && !this.state.errorMessage) {
      this.setState({ message: "Latitude: " + this.state.lat });
    } else if (!this.state.lat && this.state.errorMessage) {
      this.setState({ message: "Error: " + this.state.errorMessage });
    } else {
      this.setState({ message: "Loading..." });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.message} </div>;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What is the problem by the second way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main issues:

**1) `setState` is asynchronous**

Even if the second problem didn't exist you cannot immediately introspect state immediately after calling `setState`; the state won't have been set yet.

**2) `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous**

The callbacks for `getCurrentPosition` will execute at an indeterminate time in the future. The constructor continues to run, calling `setState` (based on current state, initialized to nulls and empty strings) before `getCurrentPosition` has likely called its callbacks.

(And there's zero reason to call `setState` in the constructor itself (as opposed to the callbacks to `getCurrentPosition`, which is fine), you can just set state directly as you do when you first initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async. `this.state` gets the new value in the next render but you're trying to use it right away.

If you want to store the message in the state, you can do that in the callbacks passed to `getCurrentPosition` and it is better to handle all that in `ComponentDidMount` rather than the constructor.

[image: Edit agitated-pond-rv6u2]

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { lat: null, errorMessage: "", message: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.setState({ lat, message: `Latitude: ${lat}` });
      },
      (err) =>
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: err.message,
          message: `Error: ${err.message}`
        })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.message} </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said the problem is in second solution, not in first

Comment: @BahadorKhajehmiri Both approaches work. I would personally still go with the first approach because React is all about rendering declaratively. `message` doesn't have to be stored in the state.